How to typehint a collections namedtuple as a function return?
I genuinely cannot find an answer to this and related questions on here (such as 1, 2) are for NamedTuple from the typing module.
How do I type hint this functions return value please?
from collections import namedtuple

def filename_strip(filepath: str) -> tuple[str, str]:
    FileValues = namedtuple("FileValues", "path_without_file filename_with_ext")
    (path_without_file, filename_with_ext) = os.path.split(filepath)
    return FileValues(path_without_file, filename_with_ext)

I know tuple is correct as it is returning a tuple but I want my code to be precise for mypy and do not know if namedtuple has a different way of type hinting, I could not see anything in the documentation online.

Why not define FileValues outside of the function? Then you can just define the return type as FileValues.

@mipadi tbh I didn't even think of that, my issue was that it just shows FileValues without their types e.g. when I hover over the function name, is that the typical way it is?

There aren't any types for the individual fields of FileValues specified, so no, you probably won't get any information on that (although perhaps some IDEs can infer it). If you want that to be type-checked as well, it's probably better to either create a FileValues class, maybe using the dataclasses module, or perhaps a TypedDict.

Really, NamedTuple is almost always preferred. It is just a thin wrapper around the old namedtuple, providing a more ergonomic and type-checker-friendly syntax: class FileValues: / path_without_file: str  / filename_with_ext: str / def filename_strip(filepath: str) -> FileValues:.

@InSync yeah I have changed it to your advice thank you. If you want to post an answer then I will gladly accept

You can close this question as a dupe of How to type hint namedtuple in Python? then.
